# Is there a way to count a value between 2 array of objects and then merge it into one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So i have this array

```
departments: [
  {
   name: 'smthg',
   persons: 0,
  },
  {
   name: 'anotherone',
   persons: 0,
  },
  {
   name: 'and anotherone',
   persons: 0,
  },
]
```

And this other array

```
persons: [
  {
   name: 'John',
   email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
   department:'smthg'
  },
  {
   name: 'Ninja',
   email: 'lalala@gmail.com',
   department:'anotherone'
  },
  {
   name: 'Tom',
   email: 'oooo@gmail.com',
   department:'anotherone'
  },
]
```

So my problem is i want to know how many personas each department has. I tried using map, and filter functions but dont know how to really aproach it.

**What i expect**

I expect departments array to be updated by some function with the right amount of people in it

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: If you want to **update** the departments array, then you need to loop over it, and then find all the persons in that department, and your count is the `.length` of the filtered results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `.map` and `.filter`:

```js
const departments = [
  {
   name: 'smthg',
   persons: 0,
  },
  {
   name: 'anotherone',
   persons: 0,
  },
  {
   name: 'and anotherone',
   persons: 0,
  }
]

const persons = [
  {
   name: 'John',
   email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
   department:'smthg'
  },
  {
   name: 'Ninja',
   email: 'lalala@gmail.com',
   department:'anotherone'
  },
  {
   name: 'Tom',
   email: 'oooo@gmail.com',
   department:'anotherone'
  }
]

console.log(
    departments.map((department) => {
        department.persons = persons.filter((person) => person.department === department.name).length;
        return department;
    })
);
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that this both creates a new array, and modifies the original array, as the new array and the old array both have the same elements in them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option that creates a `deptCount` object from the `persons` array and then loops through the `departments` array, mutating the `persons` property. This could potentially be more efficient than solutions that use loops inside of loops, but odds are there won't be enough people or departments for it to really matter.

```js
const departments = [
  {
   name: 'smthg',
   persons: 0,
  },
  {
   name: 'anotherone',
   persons: 0,
  },
  {
   name: 'and anotherone',
   persons: 0,
  },
]

const persons = [
  {
   name: 'John',
   email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
   department:'smthg'
  },
  {
   name: 'Ninja',
   email: 'lalala@gmail.com',
   department:'anotherone'
  },
  {
   name: 'Tom',
   email: 'oooo@gmail.com',
   department:'anotherone'
  },
]

const deptCounts = persons.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.department] = (acc[el.department] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

departments.forEach(dept => {
  dept.persons = (deptCounts[dept.name] || 0);
});

console.log(departments);
```

Comment: Why `dept.persons +=` ? IMHO, `dept.persons =` would be cleaner. +1 for linear time.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `updateDepartments()` will update the departments variable with the updated `persons` count

```
const departments = [
  {
    name: 'smthg',
    persons: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'anotherone',
    persons: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'and anotherone',
    persons: 0,
  },
]

const persons = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
    department:'smthg',
  },
  {
    name: 'Ninja',
    email: 'lalala@gmail.com',
    department:'anotherone',
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'oooo@gmail.com',
    department:'anotherone',
  },
]

function updateDepartments() {
  persons.forEach(person => {
    const index = departments.findIndex(department => department.name === person.department)
    if (index) {
      departments[index].persons++
    }
  })
}

updateDepartments()
```